# how to match rowname in one dataframe to another and extract the corresponding column (if present)?

Tags: r

I have a simple question, but could not figure out how to do this.

I have two dataframes `mydfa` and `mydfb`. I want to match rownames in mydfa with the rownames in `mydfb` and extract the items in column c of mydfb to mydfa (if present) and get the result.

mydfa

```
rownames  x y z  
app3      1 3 4
app2      1 4 4
app5      1 4 5
```

mydfb

```
 rownames     a b c 
    app1      5 4 2
    app3      5 5 6 
    app4      5 4 7
    app5      5 3 8
```

result

```
 rownames     x y z  c  
    app3      1 3 4  6
    app2      1 4 4  NA
    app5      1 4 5  8
```

Comment: You should read `?merge`. Try here `merge(mydfa,mydfb[,c("rownames","c")],by="rownames",all.x=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match` to work out which row name maps where, and then subset the row of the second data frame with that:

```
> mydfa$c = mydfb[match(row.names(mydfa), row.names(mydfb)),"c"]
> mydfa
     x y z  c
app3 1 3 4  6
app2 1 4 4 NA
app5 1 4 5  8
```

To see how this works, take it apart:

```
> match(row.names(mydfa), row.names(mydfb))
[1]  2 NA  4
```

which is saying the first row name in `mydfa` is the second in `mydfb`, the second rowname has no match, and the third row name matches the fourth in `mydfb`. Then the subsetting with square brackets gets the second element, an NA, and the fourth element from `mydfb$c` and creates `mydfa$c`.